Wordpress 6.6 Gutenberg "paste" event propagation from inner WYSIWYG editor
I have a custom Gutenberg plugin which adds a custom block with React Quill editor in said block. Before 6.6 version if I pasted content in Quill editor things would work as expected - content will be added into the WYSIWYG area. However since updating Wordpress to version 6.6 now paste event seems to propagate further into Gutenberg code where instead of adding copied content into WYSIWYG it adds the content as a simple "Paragraph" type block completely replacing custom active block with Quill in it.
Is there some obvious configuration option that can be changed in Wordpress or Gutenber in order to prevent paste event propagating from the Quill editor further into Gutenberg?
